# Spliting collection depending on e.g date

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, collections, docpad

I've got one collections with all files displayed on page.

Every file has its own date, and I need to split collection and display different files depending on its date - create something like archive.
I am newbie with doc pad and I don't know any efficient way to achieve this.

If I try to Google that, everything I receive is paged plugin, and I don't think it's solution to my problem - if it is, please enlighten me.

I thought perhaps creating two different collections would solve the problem, but I don't know how to check if something is for example older than a year (not from last year, but something 365 days older).

I would be grateful for every support.

Answer (score 0):

There was a question about it some time ago here: [Loop through posts' date in order to make archive in DocPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088218/loop-through-posts-date-in-order-to-make-archive-in-docpad) and the answer was very good.

Otherwise we need more details, link to github to your project and exact specification what you want to accomplish.